# how can merge array something like this below is my data What should we do Javascript?

Tags: javascript, meteor

***how can merge array something like this below is my data

What should we do *** 
All of the solutions that use reduce + concat and merge but still not work

---

```
   [
    {
     employeeName: 'វី រឿន',
     docStudyFee: 415.24,
     docBusFee: 50,
     docSaleFee: 10,
     amount: 475.24 
   },
   { items: 
     [ 
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
     ] 
   },
  ]
```

**the result like this**

```
 [{
   employeeName: 'វី រឿន',
   docStudyFee: 415.24,
   docBusFee: 50,
   docSaleFee: 10,
   amount: 475.24 ,
   items: 
       [ 
         [Object],
         [Object],
         [Object],
       ]     
  }]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Object.assign({}, ...yourArray)
```

or

```
 yourArray.reduce((obj, el) => Object.assign(obj, el), {})
```

If you really need an array with one object instead of the object directly, wrap the oneliners above into `[]`

Comment: yourArray.reduce((obj, el) => Object.assign(obj, el), {}) it work but it it is object and above it array but it not merge

Comment: @phan please try to understand my answer.